# 500 Error - Uploading An Audio File Using AcrCloud RESTful api

Tags: java, http-post

I upload an `audio file` to an `audio & video bucket`, called `demo`, using the `AcrCloud RESTful services`. I am getting a `500 Internal Server Error`. This indicates that my `signature is correct` (I was getting a `422` when the `signature was incorrect`). The part that I suspect is incorrect is the construction of the multipart post request

My Code:

```
import com.xperiel.common.logging.Loggers;
import com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpMediaType;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.MultipartContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.MultipartContent.Part;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;
import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class TestAcrCloudSignature {

  private static final String ACCESS_KEY = "xxxx"; // confidential
  private static final String SECRET_KEY = "yyyy"; // confidential
  private static final String URL = "https://api.acrcloud.com/v1/audios";

  private static HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory();
  private static final Logger logger = Loggers.getLogger();

  public static void main(String [] args) {

    String filePath = "/Users/serena/Desktop/ArcCloudMusic/Fernando.m4a";
    String httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST.toString();
    String httpUri = "/v1/audios";
    String signatureVersion = "1";
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String stringToSign = getStringToSign(httpMethod, httpUri, signatureVersion, timestamp);
    String signature = getSignature(stringToSign);

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Timestamp:\t" + timestamp);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
      ImmutableMap<String, String> params = ImmutableMap.of(
          "title", "fernando",
          "audio_id", "1",
          "bucket_name", "demo",
          "data_type", "audio");
      byte[] audio = getAudioFileTo(filePath);

      String strResponse = sendMultiPartPostRequest(
          "",
          params,
          ImmutableMap.of("audio-file", new Pair<>("Fernando.m4a", audio)),
          signatureVersion,
          signature,
          timestamp);
      logger.log(Level.INFO, "RESPONSE:" + strResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Response:  " + response);
      logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static String getStringToSign(String method, String httpUri, String signatureVersion, long timestamp) {
    String stringToSign = method+"\n"+httpUri+"\n"+ACCESS_KEY+"\n"+signatureVersion+"\n"+timestamp;
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "String to Sign:\t" + stringToSign);
    return stringToSign;
  }

  private static String getSignature(String stringToSign) {
    String signature = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(hmacSha1(stringToSign));
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Signature:\t" + signature);
    return signature;
  }

  private static byte[] hmacSha1(String toSign) {
    try {
      Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
      mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1"));
      return mac.doFinal(toSign.getBytes());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  private enum HttpMethod {
    GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,
  }

  private static byte[] getAudioFileTo(String filePath){
    File file = new File(filePath);
    byte[] buffer = null;
    try {
      InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
      fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
      fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.log(Level.WARNING, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return buffer;
  }

  private static String sendMultiPartPostRequest(
      String path,
      ImmutableMap<String, String> parameters,
      ImmutableMap<String, Pair<String, byte[]>> blobData,
      String signatureVersion,
      String signature,
      long timestamp) {
    try {
      MultipartContent multipartContent = new MultipartContent();
      multipartContent.setMediaType(new HttpMediaType("multipart/form-data"));
      multipartContent.setBoundary("--------------------------0e94e468d6023641");

      for (Entry<String, String> currentParameter : parameters.entrySet()) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.clear();
        headers.setAcceptEncoding(null);
        headers.set("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"" + currentParameter.getKey() + '\"');
        HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(null, currentParameter.getValue().getBytes());
        Part part = new Part(content);
        part.setHeaders(headers);
        multipartContent.addPart(part);
      }

      for (Entry<String, Pair<String, byte[]>> current : blobData.entrySet()) {
        ByteArrayContent currentContent = new ByteArrayContent("application/octet-stream", current.getValue().second);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.clear();
        headers.setAcceptEncoding(null);
        headers.set("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"" + current.getKey() + "\"; filename=\"" + current.getValue().first + '\"');
        headers.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        multipartContent.addPart(new Part(headers, currentContent));
      }
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      multipartContent.writeTo(out);

      HttpResponse response = requestFactory
          .buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(URL + path), multipartContent)
          .setHeaders(new HttpHeaders()
              .set("access-key", ACCESS_KEY)
              .set("signature-version", signatureVersion)
              .set("signature", signature)
              .set("timestamp", timestamp))
          .execute();
      String responseString = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(response.getContent()));
      return responseString;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  private static class Pair<A, B> {
    final A first;
    final B second;

    Pair(A first, B second) {
      this.first = first;
      this.second = second;
    }
  }
}
```

The `error message` I am getting from `AcrCloud` is:

> 500
>
> {"name":"Internal Server Error","message":"There was an error at the server.","code":0,"status":500}

I am able to upload an audio file using this `cUrl command`:

> Command: $ curl -H "access-key: xxxx" -H "signature-version: 1" -H
>   "timestamp: 1439958502089" -H "signature:
>   Nom6oajEzon260F2WzLpK3PE9e0=" -F "title=fernando" -F "audio_id=100" -F
>   "bucket_name=demo" -F "data_type=audio" -F
>   "audio_file=@/Users/serena/Desktop/ArcCloudMusic/Fernando.m4a"
>   https://api.acrcloud.com/v1/audios

Does anyone have any tips on `how to debug this`? Or has anyone had success using this service programmatically with Java? Or can someone show me how to print the contents of the HttpPOST request?

> **UPDATE**  I have also tried using their java example on GITHUB found here:
>
> https://github.com/acrcloud/webapi_example/blob/master/RESTful%20service/UploadAudios.java

I get the same `500 error`

> **UPDATE** I no longer get the `500 error` when I run their code. I fiddled with the apache jar versions and now I can successfully use the java code found on git hub. For record, The version that I used that work with their github code is apache-http-codec-1.10, apache-http-client-4.5, apache-http-core-4.4.1, apache-http-mime-4.5. **When i used apache-http-core-4.5 it did not work.**
>
> **UPDATE** I have written a file that prints out the signatures generated by the java code on github reference above, and my own code. The signatures match so I am convinced that issue in the way I am constructing the multipart post request. I have also written the contents of both post requests to file and the headers contain different information in a few spots.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Serena for your patience, our team is doing a detailed analysis on the code and the apache jars now. Hopefully will have an update soon.

For now, if anyone who has the same problems, please use the following jars as mentioned in https://github.com/acrcloud/webapi_example/blob/master/RESTful%20service/UploadAudios.java

```
// import commons-codec-<version>.jar, download from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

// import HttpClient,  download from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi
/**
 *   
 *   commons-codec-1.1*.jar
 *   commons-logging-1.*.jar
 *   httpclient-4.*.jar
 *   httpcore-4.4.1.jar
 *   httpmime-4.*.jar
 * 
 * */
```

Comment: Please note that not all jars work. I tried httpcore-4.5.jar and it was problematic. I am having success with 4.4.1.

Comment: httpcore-4.4.1 is better